# Copy sheet from current workbook to another open workbook that has always the same start of the name

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros.

I'm trying to copy a sheet "Vzorec 1" from current excel file to another opened excel file, which has a name "Financial Overview_123142_test.xlsx". The text after "Financial Overview_" is always changing.

I tried to do it with asterisk but it does not work - see below:

```
Sheets("vzorec 1").Select
Sheets("vzorec 1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Financial Overview_*.xlsx").Sheets(1 _
    )
```

Thanks in advance.
Br

Comment: Possibly? `"Financial Overview_" & * & ".xlsx"` It might just be the same though

Comment: @Davesexcel Thank you for your help, but this still gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the correct name when accessing the `Workbooks`-collection (or any other collection in VBA), wildcards will not work. So you will have to loop over all open workbooks and look for a matching name:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "Financial Overview*" Then
        Sheets("vzorec 1").Copy After:=wb.sheets(1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas for the help. It works great :)